# Transform TensorFlow LSTM to Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement LSTM layers in Keras according to TensorFlow implementation (see code below), it's a part of CRNN network to text recognition.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

def __sequence_label(self, inputdata):
"""
Implement the sequence label part of the network
:param inputdata:
:return:
"""
with tf.variable_scope('LSTMLayers'):
    # construct stack LSTM rcnn layer
    # forward LSTM cell
    fw_cell_list = [rnn.BasicLSTMCell(nh, forget_bias=1.0) for nh in [256, 256]]
    # Backward direction cells
    bw_cell_list = [rnn.BasicLSTMCell(nh, forget_bias=1.0) for nh in [256, 256]]

    stack_lstm_layer, _, _ = rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(fw_cell_list, bw_cell_list, inputdata, dtype=tf.float32)

    if self.phase.lower() == 'train':
        stack_lstm_layer = self.dropout(inputdata=stack_lstm_layer, keep_prob=0.5)

    [batch_s, _, hidden_nums] = inputdata.get_shape().as_list()  # [batch, width, 2*n_hidden]
    rnn_reshaped = tf.reshape(stack_lstm_layer, [-1, hidden_nums])  # [batch x width, 2*n_hidden]

    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_nums, 37], stddev=0.1), name="w")
    # Doing the affine projection

    logits = tf.matmul(rnn_reshaped, w)

    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [batch_s, -1, 37])

    raw_pred = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(logits), axis=2, name='raw_prediction')

    # Swap batch and batch axis
    rnn_out = tf.transpose(logits, (1, 0, 2), name='transpose_time_major')  # [width, batch, n_classes]

return rnn_out, raw_pred
```

Could anyone tell me how corresponding layers should look like in Keras?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How will this be different from the existing [LSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) layer in Keras?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not familiar with TensorFlow and it's hard to me to map this model to Keras. If it's possible to use Keras LSTM it would be great, but I don't know how to configure it to do exactly the same thing.